# total leaf count in h2o

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I made a random forest in h2o using r.  It has trees and leaves.

I want to know how many leaves.  I like to compare my total number of rows to leaves.

I have 200 trees, 8 layers deep, require 5 rows per terminal leaf.  Am I traversing much of my data?  I have 20k rows.

Is there a clean way to count the number of leaves in the h2o randomForest?

Comment: A random forest model is actually a collection of trees.  Why do you need to compute the number of leaves?

Comment: I want to use the ratio of leaves to rows to think about over-fitting or under-fitting in terms of variable importance.  If I use each row 12 times, then there is likely a problem.  If I use less than 0.5% of rows, then I could be under-sampling, even if it does look bootstrappy.  Perhaps my trees use the same row 12 times, or 0.1 times.  I want to think in terms of coverage, and don't know how to access the actual 'h2o' leaves.

Comment: This approach is not right AFAIK.  The variables which are used to split early on usually dominate the behavior of a given tree.  If you want variable importance, you should be using `importance()` or for a simpler option try the best constant model.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I use "importance", aggressively.   I have enjoyed getting into the fundamentals of the 'Boruta' package including the difference between z and gini. That is not the problem.  My problem is that in some cases I have sparse data, and the tree looks like a subset of rows are dominating the fit.  In some cases I have huge data and I want to be sure it is adequately sampled.  All the "importance" in the world is going to be meaningless if I don't make a healthy forest.  I want some better measure than an eyeball norm on a convergence plot.

Comment: What is a "row" in the context of random forests?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - input datum.  a single sample.  "sample rate" parameter in h2o speaks to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be glad to know H2O stores that information! E.g. (this is for the Iris data set)

```
m <- h2o.randomForest(1:4, 5, data)
```

When printing `m` I see:

```
number_of_trees model_size_in_bytes min_depth max_depth mean_depth min_leaves  max_leaves mean_leaves
            150               20217         1         9    3.72667          21         15     6.17333
```

So there are 926 leaves (`6.17333 * 150`).

To get it with code:

```
ms = m@model$model_summary
ms$number_of_trees * ms$mean_leaves
```